# Is there a way to pipe the output of tensorflow to a .txt file

Tags: python, tensorflow

So after running this line of code
`python -m scripts.label_image --graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --image=tf_files/106906.jpg`

my console throws an output like this:

Evaluation time (1-image): 0.294s
ClassA (score=0.97202)
ClassB (score=0.02572)
ClassC (score=0.00226)

Is there a way I can put the output into a .txt or CSV? I've tried adding a simple >output.txt to the end of the previous command but that only created an empty .txt file.

The original code looks like this:

```
for i in top_k:
   print(template.format(labels[i], results[i]))
```

Which I modified to this:

```
for i in top_k:
    outputFile = open('output.txt', 'w')
    print(template.format(labels[i], results[i]), file = outputFile)
    outputFile.close()
```

Unfortunately this only prints the last thing. Basically it prints the first message and then it puts the second one in place of the first etc. Is there a way to keep all the lines in that output.txt file?

Answer (score 1):

You could either print the output to a file with [print](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-file-parameter-print/) (3.x).

Example (from article above):

```py
# Code for printing to a file 
sample = open('samplefile.txt', 'w') 
  
print('GeeksForGeeks', file = sample) 
sample.close()
```

Or, if you are operating on bash, redirect [sys.stdout to file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file). Or for [Windows](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/redirect-output-from-command-line-to-text-file/#:%7E:text=Redirect%20Standard%20Error%20To%20a,file%20you%20want%20to%20create.&text=This%20sends%20the%20standard%20output%20stream%20to%20myoutput.).

As an alternative you could extract it by attributes, e.g. with list comprehensions, and talk advantage of [python's csv lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to save it to file.

Comment: So I went into that file and it looks something like this at the end:
  
```for i in top_k:
    print(template.format(labels[i], results[i]))```

So I tried adding the , file = "output.txt" this after that print line, thus making the code now: ```print(template.format(labels[i], results[i]), file = "output.txt")``` However that didn't work

Comment: @EnigmaticFractal added pratical example from article

Comment: I followed those changes, but now it's saying: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'. On the bright side, it is creating an output.txt file.

Comment: Please add more details to the question with what you've already tried. At this point it's hard to debug your problem with the given infos